# How to get root domain cookie from subdomain with PHP?

Tags: php

We have a website that is using a subdomain: blog.naturah.local. 
A proxy pass is set up for this, and it is pointong to: naturah.local/blog.
We are setting gdpr cookies so that we provide the domain name in order to make the cookie available for the subdomain.
When I have a look at the allowed cookied in chrome from blog.naturah.local, I can see the gdpr cookies in the list, the domain is naturah.local.
But I can not access it from $_COOKIE['gdpr_privacy_bar'] it is not set, and the alow cookies bar is always showing under the subdomain.
How can I get the values of cookies set under root doman from subdomain?

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName blog.naturah.local

      RewriteEngine on
      ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/.*$
      RewriteRule (.*) http://naturah.local/$1 [P]
      RewriteRule (.*) http://naturah.local/blog/$1 [P,E=proxy_pass_path:/blog]
      ProxyPassReverse / http://naturah.local/${proxy_pass_path}/ interpolate

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/naturah/"
      ServerName naturah.local
      ServerAlias naturah.eva.wb
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: Cookies in chrome's application tab]

[image: Header information]

Comment: Please share your proxy setup. I’d probably start by checking what HTTP request headers the PHP script receives, to see if the cookie header did even make it that far.

Comment: Please check this URL for more information : [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Comment: I have added the virtual host setup

Comment: I have also added the cookies and header info that can be seen in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I have found tha way it works.
I had to leave session domain blank in: session_set_cookie_params(),
And I have set the cookie domain without the leading dot.
It is a Kohana system runnig on php version 5.6.3, so there can be differences.

```
session_set_cookie_params(86400, '/', '', false, false);
setcookie('gdpr_privacy_bar', 1, time()+31556926, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME]);
```